# Number of packets ordered by IP

Tags: packet, iptables, tcpdump, netstat, ddos

My server is currently under a small DOS attack. I would like to know if there is an easy way to get the list of IPs sending packets to my server, ordered by the number of packet they sent, on a specific port.

I use ubuntu server 12.04

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `tshark` and use the following command:

```
sudo tshark -i wlan0 -z conv,"ip" -a duration:60 -q
```

Where `wlan0` is the interface that you wish to collect statistics on and `-a duration:60` says to collect 60 seconds worth of traffic.  Change the duration to as long as you need to collect meaningful statistics.  You will get the following output:

```
Capturing on wlan0
288 packets captured
================================================================================
IPv4 Conversations
Filter:<No Filter>
                                               |       <-      | |       ->      | |     Total     |   Rel. Start   |   Duration   |
                                               | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes |                |              |
192.168.1.77         <-> 192.168.1.64              13      1044       0         0      13      1044     1.142686000        57.2332
224.0.0.251          <-> 192.168.1.202             11      2147       0         0      11      2147     1.331480000        15.1559
239.255.255.250      <-> 192.168.1.69               7      4046       0         0       7      4046     2.358215000        48.0263
255.255.255.255      <-> 192.168.1.75               6      1296       0         0       6      1296     6.862010000        41.2681
192.168.1.255        <-> 192.168.1.75               5       582       0         0       5       582    17.716916000        30.4114
224.0.0.252          <-> 192.168.1.64               5       336       0         0       5       336     1.024354000        53.2502
239.255.255.250      <-> 192.168.1.70               4      2020       0         0       4      2020     0.924055000        48.0273
```